# s3cmd 1.6 failed too many times

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have recently updated my **s3cmd** from 1.5 to 1.6. This is the error when I try to upload files of any size. I am using the same configuration as before.

```
ERROR: Upload of ,<myfile>' failed too many times (Last reason: Upload failed  [1 of 1]

    65536 of 12125266     0% in    1s    35.22 kB/s
   786432 of 12125266     6% in    3s   244.89 kB/s
  1048576 of 12125266     8% in    4s   231.46 kB/s
  1310720 of 12125266    10% in    5s   230.23 kB/s
  1638400 of 12125266    13% in    6s   243.05 kB/s
  2097152 of 12125266    17% in    7s   262.69 kB/s
  2490368 of 12125266    20% in    8s   270.47 kB/s
  2686976 of 12125266    22% in    9s   281.29 kB/s  failed
```

Answer (score 2):

These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

The AWS CLI supports multi-part uploads, synchronizing of directories and copying of files to stdout, plus supports all API calls to AWS (not just for Amazon S3).